# Can parameter expansion handle multiple occurrence specifications

Tags: bash, shell, parameters, pattern-matching, expansion

Using the rear-anchored `name%pattern` operator on a build server, and given an input string like:

```
remainstr1-remaingstr2--9.99.9-remainstr3-20190920.115934-4.zip
```

**I need the** `20190920.115934-4.zip` **part to be removed.**

I managed to successfuly apply this transformation using *wildcard* characters and literals. But I could not get it to work by specifying multiple occurrences of a given range using the `+` quantifier. *(of course digits in the removal part can be any digits)*.

So far, the following pattern works *(of course, replacing `.*` part with `\.zip` also works)*:

```
REMAIN_STRING=${START_STRING%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9].*}
```

But this looks definitively inelegant and I would like to specify multiple occurrences of the digits characters class (`[0-9]`) but I could get it to work.

I obviously tried

```
REMAIN_STRING=${START_STRING%[0-9]+.[0-9]+-[0-9].*}
```

and also numerous possibilities with or without parentheses, backslash escapes but REMAIN_STRING simply stays the same as the START_STRING.

I also tried to store the pattern as a variable like some examples suggest:
`X="[([0-9]+)-([0-9]+).zip]"` and then: `REMAIN_STRING=${START_STRING%$X}`

But all fail!

It is now making me frustrated, even more because I get no error messages. Simply nothing happens.

So, I am asking myself: can the `name%pattern` and similar operators handle complex/extended regular expressions, or am I missing a simple escape somewhere?

Comment: I think it boils down to `shopt -s extglob` and then using `+(pattern)`; something like `${START_STRING%+([0-9]).+([0-9]).}`.

Comment: Also, `name%pattern` does *not* use regular expressions, but shell glob patterns.

Comment: `[0-9][0-9][0-9]...` just use `sed 's/[0-9]{8}\.[0-9]{6}-[0-9]\.zip$//'`..

Comment: Thanks for pointers guys. I tried the extglob suggested by Benjamin and tested several options but was unsuccessful. So switched to the "sed" command which I originally did not want to use because I am in a shell script but not reading a file. But got it to work; just had to escape the curly braces, and also added a /g to terminate the sed command. So thanks Kamil. This is the final working result: REMAIN_STRING=$( echo "${START_STRING}" | sed 's/[0-9]\{8\}\.[0-9]\{6\}-[0-9]\.zip/xx/g' )

Comment: So  PROBLEM SOLVED now

Answer (score 0):

> I tried the extglob suggested by Benjamin and tested several options but was unsuccessful.

Benjamin W.'s suggestion of setting `extglob` is good, only the given pattern is incomplete; this one works:

```
shopt -s extglob
REMAIN_STRING=${START_STRING%-+([0-9]).+([0-9])-[0-9].*}-
```